# executing R scripts from golang using Rserve and Roger

Tags: r, go, rserve

how can i execute a function from a R script via Rserve from golang using Roger...

If a function requires no arguments or just one argument, it works fine..
The problem comes when the function take two arguments.

Golang

```
//using backticks works fine too
param := "'hello'"
param2 := "'World'"
jsonx, err := rClient.Eval("parse(as.character(" + param + "," + param2 "))")
if err != nil {
    s := fmt.Sprintf("%s %s", "Error occured : ", err.Error())
    log.Println(s)
    return
}
```

R script

```
//simple
parse <- function(xx, nx) {
    print(xx)
    print(nx) 
    return(nx)
}
```

the first parameter is assigned hello but the second give an error that no default is set from the Rserve side..
How can i call a function that requires two or more parameters from golang

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
jsonx, err := rClient.Eval("parse(as.character(" + param + "," + param2 "))")
```

To:

```
jsonx, err := rClient.Eval("parse(as.character(" + param + "),as.character(" + param2 + "))")
```

For anyone like myself getting into R and integrating with Go, it can be a bit daunting. So I hope this helps someone.